# Managing MultiDependency with Maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am new to Java and maven.
I have 2 project codes(A and B) in such a way that.
A depends on B and B depends on C(third party)
But project A also depends on C.

Can I specify in pom.xml of A to take the dependency of C from B?

I just want to mention in pom.xml of A, the dependency on B and its Jars.

That way in case of any version changes of C in pom.xml of B, I won't have to do same changes in pom.xml of A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I specify in pom.xml of A to take the dependency of C from B?

If A depends on B that depends on C, A will pull transitively the dependency of C. So, you don't need to declare C in A and even you should not to avoid using different versions.

**[Transitive Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)**

> Transitive dependencies are a new feature in Maven 2.0. This allows
>   you to avoid needing to discover and specify the libraries that your
>   own dependencies require, and including them automatically.